# Update specific column on every row in a sharepoint list from power automate every Monday

Tags: power-automate, sharepoint-list

I'm building a Powerapps application where i have a sharepoint site with miltiple lists as a "Database". I'm looking to update a specific column on every row in a list that have a constant amount of rows. I want to create a power automate flow that runns every wednesday at 5:00PM and clears the column in that specific list.

Is this possible to do? Im totally new to the powerplatform.

I have searched the internet for answer but where unable to find a answer to my problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would change the SharePoint lists to Excel tables and then utilize Office Scripts to do those kinds of things.

Comment: @Ethan Thanks for the tip! But i have orders to not use Excel at datasource. It must be possible to make a http post in the code for the powerapps application, and update the rows from there...?

Comment: You can make a http post using Microsoft Graph for Microsoft Excel tables. Check out this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/table-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http